# The flow creator has exceeded their monthly flow run allotment

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have created to send emails, the flows are automatically disabled with message

`Activity Suspended`

and if I try to enable the flow it gives error message

`The flow creator has exceeded their monthly flow run allotment.`

How can we overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You need a license that that gives you more Flow executions. Please see this page for more information.

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/

Make sure you scroll down for additional information if you have an Office 365 or Dynamics 365 tenant.